# how to Get the CRUD Level Access logs for Azure Files

Tags: azure, azure-files

**how to Get the CRUD Level Access logs for Azure Files** , if any one has used it to check on who has accessed the file , any update they did or deleted the file on Azure Files . Please let me know if you can help

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enable Azure Storage Analytics Logging to capture this data,  once you do that the log data will be stored in the storage account. You can find details of enabling and accessing this [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?tabs=dotnet).